# Casting BirthDate to year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a BirthDate and i want to casting the BirthDate to year to check some condition :

```
 $"SELECT * FROM People WHERE (YEAR)BirthDate > 1960";
```

But i got a expetion :

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected, near 'BirthDate'.

Comment: Hint:  `YEAR(BirthDate)`.

Comment: My bad ... It's working sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you have applied brackets wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) > 1960
```